# Missing some code analysis warnings after switching to .NET Compiler platform analyzer

Tags: c#, visual-studio, code-analysis

While using VS 2019 RC I was suggested to [Migrate from FxCop code analysis to .NET compiler platform analyzers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/fxcop-analyzers?view=vs-2017).

I installed the corresponding NuGet packages and supressed the results from the generated code (on the project seetings code analysis page).

However, I noticed some warning are no longer displayed, like for example CA2204 (Spelling).

Is this new roslyn based analyzers a replacement for fxcop code analysis? If yes, how can I have the same checks? A follow up question would be the custom dictionaries. Are they used by the new analyzers?

Comment: To a degree, the new Roslyn-based analyzers are still work-in-progress (see the issue for CA2204: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/issues/529). However in my opinion they're enough of an improvement over the old binary analysis to warrant moving to them, and making do with the missing rules (e.g. use StyleCop for spelling)

Comment: (You can see the un-ported rules here: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/labels/FxCop-Port)